# Xamarin Forms : TabbedPage Issue. Exception in Main Activity.cs in Android project when adding children

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, portable-class-library, tabbedpage

I am building a cross-platform application with Xamarin forms(PCL).
All is good, though when I use a TabbedPage and add children to it I get the following exception in MainActivity.cs in the Android project :

```
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()[0x0000c] in < 896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf >:0
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment + InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod(Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue * args)[0x00069] in < 6cd960837cc24c26bab2a0a29b597627 >:0
   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue * parms)[0x0000e] in < 952e88faf9b94435845932f104eb293a >:0
   at Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager viewPager)[0x00060] in < 12ef52c9fdb344f58cbdf75db3fa86d8 >:0
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.TabbedPageRenderer.OnChildrenCollectionChanged(System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)[0x00085] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\TabbedPageRenderer.cs:273
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.TabbedPageRenderer.OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)[0x00114] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\TabbedPageRenderer.cs:175
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement(TElement element)[0x000f4] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:196
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)[0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:137
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)[0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.AddChild(Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean layout)[0x00015] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:250
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.SetPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page newRoot)[0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:239
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.InternalSetPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page page)[0x0009b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:382
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.SetMainPage()[0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:452
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.LoadApplication(Xamarin.Forms.Application application)[0x00183] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:136
   at App1.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)[0x000ac] in ........Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Android\MainActivity.cs:42
    -- - End of managed Java.Lang.ClassCastException stack trace-- -
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:1531)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:1484)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.access$700(TabLayout.java:1348)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:799)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:500)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:773)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:764)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:716)

at md58adf3f2592a7497b73592b5e766304c2.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)

at md58adf3f2592a7497b73592b5e766304c2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)

at android.app.ActivityThread.- wrap11(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

MainActivity.cs

```
             [Activity(Label = "App1", Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
                  Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, 
                     ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
                  ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
                    public class MainActivity : 
               global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
      {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        #region Resolver Init
        SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();
        container.Register<IDevice>(t => AndroidDevice.CurrentDevice);
        container.Register<IDisplay>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Display);
        container.Register<INetwork>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Network);

        Resolver.SetResolver(container.GetResolver());
        #endregion



        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        try
        {
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }




}
```

App.cs

```
        public App()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new HomeScreenTabbed()
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#5C8BF6")
            };

         }
```

HomeScreenTabbed.cs

```
          public HomeScreenTabbed()
          {            
             InitializeComponent();
             Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
             try
             {
                Children.Add(new ListViewPage1());
                Children.Add(new TabbedPageFirst());
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                 {
                     DisplayAlert("Exception in  RelativeLayout.Children.Add 
                     CreateUserSection", ex.ToString(), "ok");
                 });
             }
           }
```

When the 2 add children lines are commended there is no issue.
ListViewPage1 and TabbedPageFirst do not contain any code than from the one when creating them. 
Testing is performed on an emulator, Android 6.0 - API 23.
Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.3.3

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When I use `Children.Add(new ContentPage() { Title = "Page 1"})`, it works fine. So please post your `ListViewPage1` and  `TabbedPageFirst` code.

Answer (score 0):

change in App.Cs File like this

```
  public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage =new NavigationPage(new HomeScreenTabbed())
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#5C8BF6")
        };

     }
```

Comment: Thank you, i have already tried it and again unhandled exception occurs, with no info this time....

Comment: Actually, by overriding the onStart in MainActivity.cs and wrapping the base call in try catch I get                                                           Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView occurred, which does not make any sense or I cannot understand